# On running new ionic1 project i get error in my gulp file

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I downloaded and installed ionic2 project it worked fine but when i run an ionic 1 project i get this error

> Not a valid win32 application

[image]

Could someone help me to fix this issue, If i download a fresh project in ionic 1&2 everything works fine, but when i try with a old ionic 1 project i get this type of err

Comment: it looks like `node-sass` wasn't installed properly, try running `npm install` and update with output.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall gulp-saas using following command:

```
$ npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass
```

Reinstall gulp-saas using following command:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2
```

Rebuild node-sass:

```
$ npm rebuild node-sass
```